# How can I increase a counter on click and assign this value to the asp Textbox.Text?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox, counter, assign

I tried the following JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           var count = 1;
           $('#Button1').click(function () {
               count++;
               var s = document.getElementById("txtAmount");
               //s.value = count;
               s.value = String(count);
           });
       });
   </script>
```

And the TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" Text="1" CssClass="txtAmount"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Set lblTitle to be generated as a static id and then u can use jquery functions over it.